# unique_ptr after move and reassigning stuff

Tags: c++

Is it safe to do the following?

```
auto pt = getUniquePtr();
while (pt) {
  vector_of_objects.push_back(std::move(pt));
  pt = getUniquePtr();
}
```

`getUniquePtr` returns a `unique_ptr<MyObject>`. I believe that, after moving away the object, it shouldn't matter if I reassign something else to `pt`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.

Moving from an object leaves it in a *valid but unspecified state*; all the class invariants are maintained and operations act as specified.

This means that you can rely on being able to reassign, but can't make any guarantees about the current contents of the pointer.

Comment: so after moving there's no possibility of the old `unique_ptr` still somehow linking to the old object and deleting it (since `operator=` is basically a `reset(release)`), right?

Comment: @Dean move-constructing a `std::unique_ptr` from another is documented to transfer ownership, so there's no chance of that happening.

Comment: Great, that answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're worried about, but this should be absolutely safe. A unique pointer is unique. So once you've moved the pointer into the vector, `pt` is an empty pointer that you are free to re-assign.

Comment: I was afraid the moved object could still have a "link" to the old object and somehow delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe, the resources owned by `pt` no longer belongs to 'pt' thanks to the `std::move`. In my debugger that pointer would be set to the special has-been-deleted address.

In your example it might be "safer" to give `pt` a tighter scope and reduce the duplicate `getUniquePtr` call, but that's pretty marginal stylistic point.

```
while (true) {
  auto pt = getUniquePtr();
  if(pt == nullptr) break;
  vector_of_objects.push_back(std::move(pt));
}
```

Comment: @user2079303 Yep, pretty serious mistyping, sry.